# Link between the main form and sub form in ms access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, subquery

I have a form containing details of a piece of equipment that personA is currently hiring. On the same form there is a subform containing the history of hires personA has.

I would like to click on a record in the subform and have that record then appear in the main form. For arguments sake:

- main form is frmmain and is running off tlbmain
- subform is frmsubmain and is running off tblsubmain.

Could anyone tell me how I would code an onclick event to achieve this?

Thanks,

P

Comment: Without code, we can't really help. Here is a form/subform refer guide:
http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can either use continuous form or split form for this.In Create Form go to More Form and create split form that perform function as you require if you don't have additional requirements.